# xaml nested class path designer issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2010, designer

I have nested class

```
public class Enums
{
  public enum WindowModeEnum { Edit, New }
}
```

In my xaml I reference code:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowMode}"
        Value="{x:Static Types1:Enums+WindowModeEnum.Edit}">
             <Setter Property="Visibility"
                     Value="Collapsed" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Code compiles and runs properly, however I can't open xaml code in design window.  I am getting following error:

```
Type 'Types1:Enums+WindowModeEnum' was not found.
   at MS.Internal.Metadata.ExposedTypes.ValueSerializers.StaticMemberDocumentValueSerializer.ConvertToDocumentValue(ITypeMetadata type, String value, IServiceProvider documentServices)
   at MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.Markup.XamlMarkupExtensionPropertyBase.get_Value()
   at MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.DocumentPropertyWrapper.get_Value()
   at MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.InMemory.InMemoryDocumentProperty..ctor(DocumentProperty property, InMemoryDocumentItem item)
   at MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.InMemory.InMemoryDocumentItem.SetUpItem(DocumentItem item)
```

Same error exist in VS2008, VS2010.

Does anybody has any idea, how to deal with it so I can open window in design mode.

Thanks a lot.

Sincerely,
Vlad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I placed the same question to Microsoft, and they tested this scenario as well, and they admited that this is a bug on their side, and they will take a look at it.

Comment: Here is a Microsoft Connect link to the bug: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/361509/xaml-designer-cannot-handle-typename-with-nested-classes